# What is the advantage of mxml based project over pure actionscript based project?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

What are the advantages of mxml based project over a pure actionscript based project in Flash Builder. Especially, when after Flash Builder 4.6, the design mode has been removed off.

Comment: Are you asking about using Flex vs pure AS3? Or about using MXML vs AS3 within a Flex project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after smallest filesize: go for pure AS3.

If you are after ease-of-use (dev & user): go for Flex.

There is no "I'm using MXML, so I'm not using AS3", rather Flex is an extension to AS3 which will increase your filesize and RAM usage a bit but for that you can do a lot of UI related things way quicker (not just because of MXML).

So, even without design mode, using Flex for the UI design will be much more comfortable than AS3. Think about nested relative sizes ("box in a box in a box is 25% percent the width of the parent"), with Flex that is easily managed (it does it for you), with pure AS3 you will wind up in a nightmare of possible relations to calculate.

Or colors: how to transform the actual hue of a color? Modifying the RGB channels will turn out to be tricky, Flex has an HSB class, so you can convert a color to HSB (hue, saturation, brightness), manipulate it and then return it as RGB.

Eventually, especially with larger projects, you will end up with a mixture of pure-ActionScript and Flex.

Comment: Good answer, but there's really a lot more too it. You nailed it with *"there is no "I'm using MXML, so I'm not using AS3""* but there are a lot of reasons to not use Flex besides filesize and RAM, because there are alternative frameworks for "ease of use" (Feathers comes to mind, which has some support for MXML as a matter of fact) and libraries that don't require Flex. Many people have built their own UI frameworks in AS3 to get better results for their own needs, too -- it's not "a nightmare" to do. I would argue there isn't really a good non-subjective answer for Flex vs pure AS3.

Comment: In fact, I'm also one of those who built their own UI framework. That's why I meant you get into that nightmare, I figured it out the hard way. Started off with a pure-AS3 framework and eventually moved it over to Flex to make stuff easier for me (why reinvent the whole wheel?). I think, it's also a question of complexity. Using Flex (or another fitting framework) gets really useful with large projects (I'm talking about several thousand lines of code here, many custom components) because it makes it easier to separate UI and logic. And, yes, a non-subjective answer is a hard one.

Answer (score 1):

MXML is just a [declaritive markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) for Flex. Reasons for using MXML instead of AS3 in a Flex project are the same as any markup language, such as HTML in the browser.

A "pure AS3 project" typically refers to not using Flex, so it's more than not using MXML, it's also not having access to the Flex library of components.